# What does this URL mean?

Tags: coldfusion, query-string

```
http://localhost/students/index.cfm/register?action=studentreg
```

I did not understand the use of 'register' after index.cfm. Can anyone please help me understand what it could mean? There is a index.cfm file in students folder. Could register be a folder name?

Answer (score 1):

They might be using special commands within their .htaccess files to modify the URL to point to something else.

Things like pointing home.html -> index.php?p=home

Answer (score 1):

ColdFusion will execute `index.cfm`. It is up to the script to decide what to do with the `/register` that comes after.

This trick is used to build SEO friendly URL's. For example http://www.ohnuts.com/buy.cfm/bulk-nuts-seeds/almonds/roasted-salted - `buy.com` uses the `/bulk-nuts-seeds/almonds/roasted-salted` to determine which page to show.

Whats nice about this is it avoids custom 404 error handlers and URL rewrites. This makes it easier for your application to directly manage the URL's used.

I don't know if it works on all platforms, as I've only used it on IIS.

Answer (score 1):

You want to look into the `cgi.PATH_INFO` variable, it is populated automatically by CF server when such URL format used.

Better real-life example would look something like this.

I have an URL which I want to make prettier:

`http://mybikesite/index.cfm?category=bicycles&manufacturer=cannondale&model=trail-sl-4`

I can rewrite it this way:

`http://mybikesite/index.cfm/category/bicycles/manufacturer/cannondale/model/trail-sl-4`

Our `cgi.PATH_INFO` value is: `/category/bicycles/manufacturer/cannondale/model/trail-sl-4`

We can parse it using list functions to get the same data as original URL gives us automatically.

Second part of your URL is plain GET variable, it is pushed into `URL` scope as usually.

Both formats can be mixed, GET vars may be used for paging or any other secondary stuff.

Answer (score 0):

index.cfm is using either a CFIF IsDefind("register") or a CFIF #cgi.Path_Info# CONTAINS statements to execute a function or perform a logic step.